# Data structure for large 2D array data

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

I work with a simulation that outputs a 2D array of data, where each column is a different simulation variable (around 50,000 variables), and each row is each time sample (varies but often 10,000 time points or more).

This data needs to be accessed in two different ways: either get the entire time series for a small number of variables, or get every variable at a specific time point. In other words, sometimes I need to read columns from the data, and sometimes I need to read rows.

Currently the simulation spits out a binary format in row-major order. That makes it easy to get every variable for a specific time, but reading the entire time-series for a single variable is very slow, because the data is spread through the entire gigabyte-sized file.

Is there some sort of data structure that will help me? I know that I could effectively double the size of the file and store the data in both row-major and column-major order, but the files are already quite large.

There are some other questions here that I've looked through, but none seem to address this particular use case.

Comment: From what you tell us I suppose your typical data file is about 4GB.  Is that really too much to duplicate given the current cost of disk storage ?  Crikey, 16GB RAM laptops are nothing special these days, you could hold the data twice in memory !  I can guarantee that no one will offer a clever data structure which will give the same speed of access both row- and column-wise as you get currently when you read the file in the 'right' order to stream data sequentially off the disk.

Comment: Unfortunately we run many, many simulations each day. Management would not approve a sudden doubling of telemetry data. Not only would we need twice as many hard disks in our network, but we would need twice as many tape backups too.

Comment: Not that it's very relevant, but why would you need twice as many tape backups ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a disclaimer- I don't recommend implementing this data structure in your program. It wastes more time on row access than it saves on column access. However, it seems to be your only other option if you cannot increase memory size, and if you absolutely must improve column access (say, to meet some threshold to prevent stalling elsewhere), then it might be your only option.

You could adjust your 2D array such that both reading from rows and reading from columns are faster than reading from columns was previously, however reading from rows would take a substantial hit in performance. It also does mean indexing the specific locations will be slower, but the cache misses likely have more of an influence.

For simplicity, assume the matrix is of size NxN, and N is a perfect square. Now, we could arrange the ith row of the original matrix to be spread out across a 1D matrix at every `i + k * sqrt(N)` element. The jth column would appear in batches of `sqrt(N)` inbetween (and intersecting) these stretches between rows. So something like `floor(index / sqrt(N)) * N + index mod sqrt(N)`.

What this accomplishes is every N elements, you now have sqrt(N) elements for respective rows and columns, rather than N row elements but only 1 column element. When you pull in a cache line, you'll now have several of each element (giving at least a few cache hits), regardless of whether you are traversing the rows or columns, rather than risking "all or nothing". Whether this is a good trade off depends on how badly you need to improve worst case performance and how much you care about best case performance.

To transform an existing 2D array to this form, you can take the rows that make up the lower half of the matrix, and interleave their columns with their respective upper half rows. Then take the right half of this elongated matrix, and interleave its rows with the rows of the left half. Repeat `sqrt(N)` times. Note this would be horribly slow- and I'm not suggesting you use this to convert your database over, I'm just providing it as another means to understand the data structure. To convert a database over, I'd work out the formulas, and then move each element one by one.